# Missing Style tab of the widget wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using elementor and wpForm plugins, I have a problem when attache the form using wpform widget, elementor does not appear STYLE tab, I tried to reinstall elememntor but still have the problem.

Comment: Please direct this to plugin/theme developers, it is out of scope for StackOverflow. We are not technical support.

Comment: @GhostPengy still has the courage and the sword. I gave up a long time ago. The quest is yours.